# Composer installation error on WAMP windows

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php, wampserver

I am using the WAMP server on Windows system.
I tried to install composer following instructions from this [site](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). so basically download and run [Composer-Setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe). But during the installation, I received the following error:

> The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].
>
> OpenSSL failed with a 'certificate verify failed' error. This
> indicates a problem with the Certificate Authority file(s) on your
> system, which either cannot be found or may be out of date.
>
> Script Output: The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not
> be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
> messages: error:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
> Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed

I searched solutions online, it seems the cacert.pem file is missing. So I download the file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and placed it in the php folder:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\cacert.pe
```

Then, I set the path of openssl.cafile and openssl.capath in php.ini

```
openssl.cafile="c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\cacert.pem"
openssl.capath="c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21"
```

But still get the same error.
I checked php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());", the output is

```
Command line code:1:
array(8) {
  'default_cert_file' =>
  string(25) "C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem"
  'default_cert_file_env' =>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  'default_cert_dir' =>
  string(22) "C:\usr\local\ssl/certs"
  'default_cert_dir_env' =>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  'default_private_dir' =>
  string(24) "C:\usr\local\ssl/private"
  'default_default_cert_area' =>
  string(16) "C:\usr\local\ssl"
  'ini_cafile' =>
  string(0) ""
  'ini_capath' =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

So the default folder is "C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem", I don't know which folder is it in windows wamp and couldn't find a answer online.
what can I do more to make this work?

Comment: See [Point 8 - How to Install Composer in WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,161050)

Comment: Same problem here. And the command-line installation leads to the same problem.